# Programming environment?

Tags: linux, bash, ps1

I'm trying to add color to a part of my Ubuntu bash prompt.
This part isn't working: (\e[0;31m\1\e[m)
It works, however, if I place it within the PS1 export.

What am I doing wrong?

```
show_git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\e\[0;31m\1\e\[m) /'
}

export PS1="\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$(show_git_branch)\$ "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's imagine you asked this question:

- Why does putting `\e\[0;31m` in `PS1` variable content result in a colored text output, when putting the same string inside `sed` `s` command replacement expression does not result in colored output?

It's because Bash when printing the content of `PS1` variable changes the sequence of two characters `\` and `e` by the byte with the value 033 octal or 0x1b hexadecimal. In contrast, for `sed` the sequence of `\` `e` characters as part of replacement expression is technically invalid and in practice is not interpreted specially and with GNU `sed` just results in a literal `e` character on output.

If you want to output the hex byte 0x1b with GNU `sed` you can use the `\x1b` escape sequence, or you can rely on Bash ANSI-C quoting to pass the byte literally to sed.

```
echo a | sed 's/^/\x1b\[31m/'
# or
echo a | sed 's/^/'$'\e''\[31m/'
# the same
echo a | sed 's/^/'$'\E''\[31m/'
```